# How to implement directive with animation in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular2-animation

I am currently working on an Angular 2 project.

The project is generated with angular-cli v1.0.0-beta.15.

I am now thinking to implement a reusable directive which trigger specific animation. As it is lack of documentation for this currently, anyone has any idea to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

No luck, still not implemented, see https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9947

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39463660/1448419 provide some solution for reusable animation definition to be used in multiple components.

Comment: thanks. seems like it is the only way now. I will follow it then.