# Angular 2 - controlling animation keyframes

Tags: angular, angular2-animation

I'm trying to find a way to control CSS3/ angular 2 animations.

For example, look at the following code from the offical angular 2 animation docs with some changes:

```
animations: [
  trigger('flyInOut', [
    state('in', style({position: 'absolute', left: '15%',bottom:'15%'})),
    transition('void => *', [
      animate(300, keyframes([
        style({opacity: 0, left: '30%', offset: 0}),
        style({opacity: 1, left: '50%',  offset: 0.3}),
        style({opacity: 1, left:'80%',     offset: 1.0})
      ]))
    ])
  ])
]
```

My question is that if there is any way to control the css values with angular 2 variables. An illustration would be:

```
<animation leftPrec="15%" bottomPrec="15%" firstStep="30%" secondStep="60%" thirdStep="80%"></animation>
```

and in the animation component:

```
animations: [
      trigger('flyInOut', [
        state('in', style({position: 'absolute', left: leftPrec,bottom:bottomPrec})),
        transition('void => *', [
          animate(300, keyframes([
            style({opacity: 0, left: firstStep, offset: 0}),
            style({opacity: 1, left: secondStep,  offset: 0.3}),
            style({opacity: 1, left: thirdStep,     offset: 1.0})
          ]))
        ])
      ])
    ]
```

This demo obviously not working and written for illustration for what i'm trying to achieve.

I would love to hear if you have any way or suggestion about how to achieve something similar in order to control the animation keyframes properties.

Comment: It seems that this is not possible with the current Angular animations api. But this answer might provide you with a useful workaround :
http://stackoverflow.com/a/39463660/2025271

Answer (score 1):

you can now perform a re-usable animation using useAnimation();

```
export const easeInOutCubic = 'cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1.000)';

export const zaFade = animation([
     style({ opacity: ' {{ from }} ', transformOrigin: '50% 0%' }),
     animate('{{ time }}',
     style({ opacity: ' {{ to }} ', transform: ' {{ transform  }}' }))
], { params: { time: `1000ms ${easeInOutCubic}`, from: 1, to: 0, 
     transform: 'translateX(0)' }}
);
```

then USE the animation somewhere else and you can change the default params.

```
query('button', stagger('300ms', [
          useAnimation(zaFade, { params:
              {
                time: `1000ms ${easeInOutCubic}`,
                from: '0',
                to: '1',
                transform: 'translateY(0px)'}
            }
          )
        ]), { optional: true }),
```